# Access third party-loaded requireJS package in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, symfony, callback, requirejs, intl-tel-input

I am trying to work out how to access the [Intl-Tel-Input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) library inside my requireJS JavaScript. I have the following code and I need the callback to be outside of the requireJS module as it is being accessed by 3rd party code.

How can I access the `intlTelInput` code inside the `callback` function?

In my Twig template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['crmpicco/details'], function(details) {
        details.init();
    });
    var callback = function (response) {            
        // I want to access intlTelInput in here    
    };
</script>
```

I have this in my `config.js`:

```
require = {
    baseUrl: '/assets/js',
    paths: {
        'intl-tel-input': '/assets/vendor/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'intl-tel-input': {
            deps: ['libphonenumber-utils']
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: In their source they support UMD, so I guess you can use `require(['intl-tel-input'], function (IntlTelInput) {};` inside callback. And no need for shimming.

Comment: @Andrey Do you know how that should be implemented? If the `callback` is inside the `require` then the 3rd party code can't find the callback function.

Comment: @Andrey Similarly, if the `require` is inside the `callback` then the `intlTelInput` cannot be found. `TypeError: intlTelInput is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need something like this snippet,
please take a look

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.10/css/intlTelInput.css" />
  <script>
    require.config({
      paths: {
        'intl-tel-input': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.10/js/intlTelInput',
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min'
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <input id="some-input" />
  <script>
    require(['intl-tel-input'], function () {
      function someCallback(){
        $('#some-input').intlTelInput();
      }

      setTimeout(someCallback, 1000);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What is the purpose of the `setTimeout` here? Did you see my comments above?

Comment: @crmpicco, setTimeout is just to demonstrate that you can initialize intlTelInput inside asynchronous callback

Comment: Unfortunately that can't be done inside a `require` of 'intl-tel-input`. See the source on Google's invisible reCaptcha demo for what I am trying to achieve - https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true .

Comment: See my PR on the EWZReCaptcha project at https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/pull/154 and my fork for a workable solution https://github.com/crmpicco/EWZRecaptchaBundle/commits/master